# Calling a function with parameters in href attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm calling a function with one parameter from an `innerHTML` property but nothing was displayed this is my code:

```
var myVar="Ali";
      summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:sayHello("+ myVar+");'>" + "Say Hello" + "</a>";


 function sayHello(myVar)
{   
        window.alert(myVar);
}
```

Comment: You need to have a trigger for that function.  Right now all you are doing is creating an HREF, with no actual trigger, and no closing tag.

Comment: Assuming the link can be clicked and it gets clicked: Have a look at the console. You'll see an error. Hint: string literal, quotation marks.

Comment: hey bro check out my answer it might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click me'));
a.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sayHello(myVar);
}, false);
summaryPanel.appendChild(a);
```

Some notes:

- Avoid inline event handlers, which require global functions
- Avoid polluting global scope
- Avoid building html elements from strings using untrusted variables (may be the case of `myVar`). This practice is vulnerable to html injection.
- Avoid `htmlElement.innerHTML += something`. This will erase all data and event handlers added to previous elements inside `htmlElement`

Comment: Alternatively, if the notes above don't matter to you, use `"<a href='javascript:sayHello(\""+ myVar+"\");'>Click me</a>"`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rgy0kxa8/)

Comment: Thanks you very much Oriol for the notes it helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the function with parameter in href you need to escape the double quotes please refer the below syntax.

```
return "<a  hreg ='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showErrorPopup(\""+message+"\")'>"+value+"</a>";
function showErrorPopup(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

> where i have used \ to escape the double quotes

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var myVar = "Ali";

summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='sayHello("+myVar+")' />";

function sayHello(param){
        windows.alert(param);
}
```

Comment: Your solution has the same problem as the OP's code.